# How can I be notified or change case status if a community user adds an attachment to a case?

Tags: case, attachment, customer-community

I'd like to be notified (or at least change case status) if/when a customer adds an attachment via the community portal.  Is that possible? As per this idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpuqAAC), it sounds like it's not available.  Before completely giving up though, I thought I'd check and see.  Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If it does not work with standard functionality, you could help yourself and use the Apex Scheduler to run a piece of Apex and check for new Attachments and if so do your update/notification.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

I think using Workflows or Triggers directly you can't hook into the creation of an Attachment and most likely the Case object won't be update on new attachment.